# how to fix xcode warning "Expression result unused"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, warnings

I am doing a registration process with my app where the user enters in a number that I check against my db.. anyway long story short where I pass **code** into my **NSString *startURL**  have a warning I cannot get rid of, it says

"Expression result unused"

have you ever experienced anything like this and if so how do I fix it?

```
   -(void)startRegConnect:(NSString *)tempRegCode{

        //tempRegCode = S.checkString;
        NSLog(@"tempRegCode from RegConnection =%@",tempRegCode);


        NSString *code = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:tempRegCode];
        //urlstart string
        NSString *startURL = (@"http://188.162.17.44:8777/ICService/?RegCode=%@",code); //warning here

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:startURL];

        //create a request object with that url
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30];

        //clear out the exisiting connection if there is on
        if (connectionInProgress) {
            [connectionInProgress cancel];
            [connectionInProgress release];
        }

        //Instantiate the object to hold all incoming data
        [cookieData release];
        cookieData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

        //create and initiate the connection - non-blocking
        connectionInProgress = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    }
```

Comment: This isn't the answer to your question, but why do you allocate a new string ('code') and then assign it the value of tempRegCode? You can use tempRegCode as is without any problems.

Comment: I was only doing that thinking it might fix the problem, since I didnt know why the problem was happening I thought it might have been something weird like that, I have since changed my code without passing the incoming string to another string.

Comment: Fair enough - we've all had those moments :)

Comment: :) yea yesterday was a shocker! made sure I had a good sleep last night! thats my key to sucsess.. lots of sleep.. and sugar... :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't just do `(@"http://188.162.17.44:8777/ICService/?RegCode=%@",code)`. Use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://188.162.17.44:8777/ICService/?RegCode=%@", tempRegCode]`.

Comment: thanks, I know this... was having one of those where the heck has my head gone days! lol thanks for pointing out the obvious!

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the parenthesis. By writing (blabla) it becomes an expression, which you are not using as an expressing, hence the compiler complains.

Change to `[NSString stringWithFormat: ...];` and it becomes a method.