# Objective-C (Expression result unused)

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to fix xcode warning “Expression result unused”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688764/how-to-fix-xcode-warning-expression-result-unused)

I am having a problem that I do not now how to get rid of.

I wrote this line of code:

```
- (IBAction)submitButton:(id)sender {

    int age = ([ageField.text intValue]);
    int money = ([moneyField.text integerValue]);

    whatYouGet.text = @"%i",(age/2+7)-(money/500000);   

}
```

And I can not run it because it always say "Expression result unused".
Why? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5):

It's kind of the same question as it is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6688783/66414

You can't do @"..." with variables. You need to create a new NSStringWithFormat to pass this to your variable:

```
whatYouGet.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",(age/2+7)-(money/500000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote
[moneyField.text integerValue]

Try writing this
[moneyField.text intValue]

If it doesn't work, just create an int with that expression and then put it into your string.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
whatYouGet.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",(age/2+7)-(money/500000)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just write `@"%i",(age/2+7)-(money/500000);`

You have to use `whatYouGet.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat@"%i", (age/2+7)-(money/500000)];`

Comment: There is no need to use alloc init here :)